# Ubuntu 20.04 (and 19.10), the whole computer keeps freezing when playing with games

Tags: freeze

i dont know what is causing it to freeze, all i know is that it happens while playing to some games (i only play with Factorio and Minecraft, and i experienced freezes with both games). Sometimes it happens when i leave the laptop open for a little while. i maybe guess that its a memory overload, but it doesnt seem likeli, since with the "free" line it gave me this result:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3933868     1110256     1259964      191904     1563648     2373964
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

it's been happening for quite a while, since even before 20.04 came out.

help, if the specs are needed, i will provide em'.

edit asked:

> sysctl vm.swappiness result:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

> top result:

[these are the top results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ssFo.png)

> sudo grep -i swap /etc/fstab result:

```
1678 "name"    20   0 3751376 174480  46848 R   4,3   4,4 124:10.55 gnome-s+
```

Answer (score 1):

With only 4G RAM, a 2G /swapfile is probably too small. We'll enlarge it to 4G.

**Note**: Consider adding more RAM. Configure RAM to be equal sized (SO)DIMM pairs to take speed advantage of memory interleaving. So if you have one 4G (SO)DIMM now, add another 4G (SO)DIMM.

---

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: allright, done ill see if it freezes again in the next days and update you, i am doing these operations in a laptop, and adding more ram is not possible.

Comment: @UfaiX04 Keep me posted. Does `free -h` now show 4G swap? If there's still a problem, we'll adjust the vm.swappiness setting. Why couldn't you add more RAM? What make/model # of computer?

Comment: free -h gives this result: 

`                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3,8Gi       1,3Gi       810Mi       192Mi       1,6Gi       2,0Gi
Swap:         4,0Gi          0B       4,0Gi`

mine is a cheap laptop, it doesnt have the typical setup of a laptop. adding more ram would be a waste of money since i only use this for 2 games and am planning to buy a desktop pc in the future/near future.

Comment: @UfaiX04 How is it working now?

Comment: nope, i am having freezes still, maybe the game is too heavy, i dont know

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.